# Redirect subdomain to CakePHP action

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

### Background

I have a CakePHP application that lives in `/m/`. I want to write a root-level `.htaccess` file which will redirect "subdomains" for the site as parameters to actions.

For example: I want to write a rewrite rule which will result in redirects like this -

- `http://mysite.myserver.com` → `http://myserver.com/m/mysite/`
- `http://mysite.myserver.com/home` → `http://myserver.com/m/mysite/home`
- `http://mysite.myserver.com/foo/bar?baz=true` → `http://myserver.com/m/mysite/foo/bar?baz=true`

Ideally, this redirect should be invisible to users (I don't want to use a 301, because I don't want to change the URL).

Here's my current attempt:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.myserver\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myserver.com/m/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

As far as I can tell, the main issue is with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

- If I browse to `http://myserver.com/m/mysite/home` directly, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = /m/mysite/home`.
- If I browse to `http://mysite.myserver.com/home` using the `.htaccess` file above, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = /home`.

### The Issue

Because of the issues with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, my routes aren't parsing correctly: it's trying to take the user to `/home` rather than `/m/mysite/home` as desired.

How can I change my rewrite rule to make this work properly? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work right now, with the way the `.htaccess` file is written.

Comment: I'm not sure where you think `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` comes into play, but that's just a PHP constant holding the part behind the domain name (e.g. /index.php). It doesn't have anything to do with rewriting. A quick peek suggests that the `sites` bit after the /m/ in your RewriteRule is not mentioned in the rest of your question, are you sure it's supposed to be there?

Comment: @Oldskool: thanks for pointing out the `sites` bit, but that was just a typo. The reason I pointed out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is because, ideally, I'd like to "spoof" it somehow.

I believe that CakePHP is using that variable to parse the route, which is why (even though my `.htaccess` rule _technically_ points to the right URL) it isn't working. Is there a way to fix this with `.htaccess` rules at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking (change the domain name in URL but don't let browser see URL change) is not achievable under normal scenario. However to make it possible you have **enable** `mod_proxy` in your Apache and restart it. Once that is done use following code in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^m/ http://myserver.com/m/sites/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,P]
```