# CakePHP URL redirect

Tags: cakephp, dns, redirect

I have a similar question to the one listed here:
[Redirect subdomain to CakePHP action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438577/redirect-subdomain-to-cakephp-action)

The difference (I think) is that I have a website hosted on cloud Ubuntu servers and written in CakePHP. What I need to do is redirect:

subdomain.mysite.com --> www.mysite.com/subdomain

I am (no doubt evident from the question) a newbie at these matters, so if changing .htaccess or using mod_proxy etc then please can you explain where to find the files and what code to add (I can navigate around ubuntu, and I have previously used mod_proxy)

Many thanks

Comment: Is `mod_proxy` enabled on your cloud's Apache? (You will need to ask this from your cloud admins)

Comment: Yes it is enabled ... (I am the admin ... hence my challenges!!)